# Migrating from subscription event processor to tracking event processor

Tags: java, cqrs, axon

So we are slowly trying to migrate to tracking processors. As part of that we created a new processing group for a new event that writes to Elasticsearch and set that to use the tracking processor (default is subscription).

Everything works fine from now onwards. But there are a whole bunch of events that were generated in the past that I want the new processing group eventhandler to process.

I took a look at the `token_entry` table but not too sure how to reset it.

For example this seems to be the token (blob) as a string

```
<org.axonframework.eventhandling.GlobalSequenceTrackingToken><globalIndex>1794</globalIndex></org.axonframework.eventhandling.GlobalSequenceTrackingToken>,<org.axonframework.eventhandling.GlobalSequenceTrackingToken><globalIndex>22966</globalIndex></org.axonframework.eventhandling.GlobalSequenceTrackingToken>,<org.axonframework.eventhandling.GlobalSequenceTrackingToken><globalIndex>22966</globalIndex></org.axonframework.eventhandling.GlobalSequenceTrackingToken>,<org.axonframework.eventhandling.GlobalSequenceTrackingToken><globalIndex>22966</globalIndex></org.axonframework.eventhandling.GlobalSequenceTrackingToken>
```

Preferably would like to reset this manually.

Answer (score 2):

To reset a `StreamingEventProcessor`, like the `TrackingEventProcessor` (TEP), you can invoke the `StreamingEventProcessor#resetTokens` method on the right instance.

To find the right instance, you can use the `EventProcessingConfiguration#eventProcessor(String, Class)` method to retrieve an `Optional` containing the `EventProcessor`. If you provide `TrackingEventProcessor.class` for the' Class' parameter, the framework will automatically cast it to a TEP instance.

Although you could also adjust the stored `TrackingToken` directly, this isn't recommended. If you change it in the database, then the framework doesn't know you are doing a replay. Hence, you'd lose the benefits of Axon's Replay API. You can check out the Reference Guide on the subject [here](https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/axon-framework/events/event-processors#replaying-events), by the way.